# Custom access given to Admin dashboard

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, admin-menu, dashboard

In my site I like to give admin dashboard access to Staff members,But in some custom ares should be denied.For example Like blue color area can be access but red color area should be denied.

[image]

How can I do ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We'd love to help but we need a reproducible issue. Posting a screenshot and that little bit of information only gots us at loss. What have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck, how can we reproduce your issue? Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) and update your question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: @leymannx I do not try any,because I'm stuck in first step, how can I start to do this .

Comment: http://www.letmegooglethat.com/?q=wordpress+user+role+permissions

Comment: @leymannx the site can't be reached

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=wordpress+user+role+permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is too broad and you do not specify what they should be allowed to access the answer is also broad. you can modify the role system with the "user role editor" plugin.

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

It's for setting specific rights for user roles like for Admin, subscriber or even shop roles in woocommerce. If the right you explicitely need is not provided you need to add it programmatically. But for the first i would try that plugin.

Comment: thank you for answered, My question is updated.

Comment: why the downvote? The answer to the question was correct.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't provide any useful information at all. How would the mentioned plugin help OP to solve their problem? Where would they find that plugin? What is it for?

Comment: :D so that is why you provide a lmgtfy link? :D haha poor. Over and out.

Comment: @lsh updated my answer

Comment: My link to LMGTFY is a comment. That's the difference.